# Joining two tables AngularFire2 Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I decided to denormalise my Firebase Database to try and make joining easier, however I'm still in the position I was before denormalising.

The issue is this:

I connect to the user_address table and filter addresss based off the location passed in, which will be the State.

Each address entry has a user profile Id i.e `$key` I then use this to connect to the profile table and retrieve the profile that matches the `$key` passed in.

this is my code so far:

```
getSearchResults(location: string): Observable<any[]> {

    var usersAddress = this.af.database.list('/user_address/', {
        query: {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'State',
                equalTo: location
            }
        }
    }).map(address => {
         address.map(entry => {
            entry.profile = this.af.database.object('/users/' + entry.$key)
         });

         console.log(address);

         return address;
    });


     return usersAddress;

}
```

Two issues.

1) When I remove `return userAddress` I get the red error line under `Observable<any[]>` which reads: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

2) when `console.log(address)` is run I see the following:

[image]

Issue here is profile is of type: `FirebaseObjectObservable` where as I expected to see the users profile...

Can anyone shed any light into how I can resolve this? I personally feel the way I've written the code so far isn't quite right i.e having two return statements is an obvious issue.

** Update **

Ok so this code is working as doing as expected:

```
this.results = this.af.database.list('/user_address/', {
            query: {
                query: {
                    orderByChild: 'State',
                    equalTo: location
                }
            }
        }).map(addresss => {
            addresss.map(address => {
                this.af.database.object('/users/' + address.$key)
                    .subscribe(user => {
                        address.userdata = user;
                    });
                this.af.database.list('/user_photos/' + address.$key, {
                    query: {
                        orderByChild: 'Profile_Pic',
                        equalTo: true
                    }
                }).subscribe(photo => {
                    address.photos = photo;
                })
                return address;
            })
            return addresss;
        });
        return this.results
```

However I see two entries in the console warning about an .indexOn : 
`FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "Profile_Pic" at /user_photos/uuBldNXtXlSvK1fOKMTQzCKMqlj2 to your security rules for better performance`

which I know how to fix, but as I'm seeing two i can only assume this is returning two data sets maybe?

Comment: Hello @Code Ratchet, so you got this join working? Can you helpe me with my case, is a joing like this, but i coudn't do your code work for me.

Comment: I actually gave up on `Firebase`, not because of this join issue but because of the limitations `Firebase` has.  I personally don't feel `Firebase` is suitable for enterprise level applications.  However I will use `Firebase` for mock designs etc but that's as far as it goes.